# Updates through WSUS fails on Windows 8.1 with error 0x80070643

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, modern-ui, wsus

I have wsus on windows server 2008 and i have two machines with windows 8.1 where updates fail with error 0x80070643.

There are exactly 8 updates that fail:
KB3080457
KB3081397
KB3081398
KB3081399
KB3081401
KB3081402
KB3081403
KB3081405

I have checked a few of them, and they seem to be metro app updates. This machine is joined to a domain and has most metro apps deleted via Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online
and Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage which i think it's what causing this problem.

Should i just hide the 8 updates and block them off WSUS and call it a day or do i have another solution?

Comment: seems my initial analisys was correct, therefore i blocked the updates from wsus, since we don't use metro here

Answer (score 2):

We had the same error with those 8 updates.  After reviewing the updates on Microsoft, I saw that they were updates for Appx that are removed from our corporate Windows 8.1 image.  Somehow, the Windows Update agent tries to install an update for an Appx that is not installed on the machine.

I removed those updates from my August Update Group.

YMMV

Comment: +1 - we hit the same problem, same exact 8 updates. We uninstall almost all Appx packages on our new images.

Answer (score 1):

We also had update failures with exactly those updates. Regarding so http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/windows-update-error-80070643#1TC=windows-7 it is mostly a problem with Office 2003 (!) Components or .NET-Framework. In our case, it helped to simply start the "Office Source Engine"-Service in the services.msc Snap-In on those maschines or
via CMD:

```
sc start ose
```

In large enviroments I whould create Group Policy which sets the OSE-Service to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" or use Powershell-Scripting:

```
$pcs = @("PC01", "PC02", "PC03")
Set-Service -Name ose -StartupType Automatic -Status Running -ComputerName $pcs
```

Hope this helps,

SaPl